# R: Use data from csv as arguments in a Shiny ui functions

Tags: r, shiny

This concerns Shiny and is rather conceptual, hence there is no reproducible example since I dont even know where to start.

**Question**: Is it possible to use the values given in the columns of some csv file as arguments to some ui function like e.g. `numericInput()`? If yes, how would I do that?

**Conceptual example**: Suppose I have a csv file named `foo`  with one column called `x` that has one row with the value `5`. Is it possible to use this csv file as an argument to a function like `numericInput()`. It should probably be something like that:

```
# read the data (not sure where to do that. In the server file? as a reactive?

mydata <- read.csv("foo.csv")

# Use data as argument

numericInput("some id", label = NULL, value = mydata$x)
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the combination of `fileInput()` (ui function) and `observe( { update__Input() } )` (server functions; e.g., `updateNumericInput()`) can renew some ui functions' arguments depending on a single value a csv file gives. But as far as I know, with a few exceptions (e.g., `selectInput()`'s argument, choices), more than one length vector can't be most arguments. So I used `selectInput()` to use all values in a column as an argument.
Here is my example app.R. Every time you input a csv file, some ui functions' arguments update (`selectInput("row.value")`'s choices depending on the values given in the column; `numericInput("col")` and `sliderInput("row")`'s max, `sliderInput("range")`'s min, max, and value depending on a single value (e.g., `nrow(data)`, `mean(a column)`) ). And everytime you change "col", "row.value" and "range" update. I think there's much room for improvement in this code.

## app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label="Input File:"),
      br(),
      numericInput("col", "col :", min = 1, max = 2, value = 1, step = 1),
      sliderInput("row", "row :", min = 1, max = 2, value = 1, step = 1),
      selectInput("row.value", "row.value :", choices = 1, selectize = F, size = 10),
      br(),
      sliderInput("range", "range :", min = 1, max = 2, value = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      br(),
      h5("Result :"),
      verbatimTextOutput("result1"),
      br(),
      h5("Data Table :"),
      dataTableOutput("table1")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    file <- input$file
    if(is.null(file)) { } else {
      data <- read.csv(file$datapath)
      col.data <- as.numeric(data[,input$col])
      updateNumericInput(session, "col", "col :", min = 1, max = ncol(data), value = NULL, step = 1)
      updateSliderInput(session, "row", "row :", min = 1, max = nrow(data), value = NULL, step = 1)
      updateSelectInput(session, "row.value", "row.value :", choices = sort(unique(col.data)))
      updateSliderInput(session, "range", "range & mean :", min = min(col.data), 
                        max = max(col.data), value = mean(col.data))
    }
  }) 
  output$result1 <- renderText({
    file <- input$file
    if(is.null(file)) { } else {
      data <- read.csv(file$datapath)
      c( paste0(iconv(file$name), "["), input$row, ",",input$col, "] is", data[input$row, input$col], 
         ";  Index of", paste0(iconv(file$name), "[value =="), input$row.value, ",", input$col, "] is", 
         which(as.numeric(data[,input$col]) == input$row.value))
    }
  })
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    file <- input$file
    if(is.null(file)) { } else {
      read.csv(file$datapath)
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: plot]